# photoelectric equation explanation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, relativity, photoelectric-effect

how to determine whether or not relativistic mechanics is needed to verify the photoelectric equation with a 1% uncertainty. While the stopping potentials are few volts.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the speed of the electron for several eV of kinetic energy and compare it to the speed of light.

Answer (score 0):

In the non-relativistic case the kinetic energy is just the usual formula:

$$ T = \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 $$

In relativistic mechanics the total energy, i.e. the sum of the KE and rest mass energy, is:

$$ E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4 $$

This is a very important equation to know as it crops up all over the place when you start working with special relativity. Anyhow, if we take the square root of both sides we get:

$$\begin{align}
E &= \sqrt{p^2c^2 + m^2c^4} \\
  &= mc^2\sqrt{1 + \frac{p^2}{m^2c^2}} 
\end{align}$$

If the momentum is small compared with the rest mass energy we can expand the square root using a binomial expansion and drop the higher order terms to get:

$$ E \approx mc^2 ( 1 + \frac{p^2}{2m^2c^2}) $$

This is an approximation for the total energy, so if we subtract off the rest mass energy $mc^2$ we'll get the kinetic energy:

$$ T \approx \frac{p^2}{2m} $$

The final step is to note that the relativistic expression for the momentum is:

$$ p = \gamma m v $$

where $\gamma$ is the [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor). And finally this gives us:

$$ T \approx \gamma^2 \tfrac{1}{2} mv^2 $$

So the end result is that the relativitic kinetic energy is the usual non-relativistic expression multiplied by the [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) $\gamma^2$. For an error of $1$% you simply set $\gamma^2 = 1.01$ and solve the resulting equation for the velocity:

$$ \gamma^2 = \frac{1}{1 - v^2/c^2} = 1.01 $$

Comment: thank you... I would like to ask is there any derivation through which this lorentz factor is set to 1.01 ?

Comment: @NailaNawaz yes, $1.01$ is a difference from the non-relativistic energy of $1$% i.e. $1.01 = 101$%.